# When I play a video full screen after about ten minutes the screen goes black, and the sound repeats a loop

Tags: 12.04, video, vlc, youtube

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I had to reinstall the OS on this computer. I didn't have this problem before. This happens in VLC, and youtube. If I'll play a video in full screen, the screen will go black after about ten minutes, and the sound will kind of repeat over, and over where it went black. The only way to fix it is to restart the computer. I can't even get my screen to go back on after that happens.

Now it's not only when it's full screen. When I watch youtube videos at their regular size my screen will go black after a while, and I have to restart it.

Comment: Does pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 then Ctrl+Alt+F7 get it working again?

Comment: It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Same problem here! Both in 12.04 and 14.04 64 Bit

Comment: What about other flash items - games etc?

Comment: I really don't know. I was watching some youtube videos a few minutes ago, and it did it again. It's really just with any type of videos. Before I reinstalled it, it was fine. I want to avoid reinstalling again, because I have a bunch of music that I don't want to lose.

Comment: Hello. This sounds like a bug report more than a question. Please consider reporting it so that it can be fixed. For that open your terminal and type `ubuntu-bug vlc` and then follow instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you guys checked the power settings on your systems? I believe the default is to put the display to "sleep mode" after 10 minutes, and then the setting are defaulted to lock the system when the screen does go to sleep.
Go to your system settings and check those, if they are set to put the screen to sleep, change the setting to a longer time, usually 2 hours is sufficient, and uncheck the box that says "Lock screen when going to sleep" hopefully that will solve your problem.